# Spring Cloud Producer exception - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform operation after producer has been closed

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, cloud, producer

Spring Cloud Producer throwing exception - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform operation after producer has been closed

Hi
We gave a spring cloud based microservice application. In that application we are getting error while producing the message to Kafka. We are using following Spring Cloud version.

Spring Cloud Version

Greenwich.SR1

Following are our interface defination which is used by the Kafka producer

```
    String INPUT = "jobmanager-in";
String OUTPUT_C = "collection-out";
String OUTPUT_P = "parser-out";
String OUTPUT_CMP = "compare-out";
String OUTPUT_R = "report-out";
String OUTPUT_N = "notification-out";

@Input(INPUT)
SubscribableChannel inboundJobManager();

@Output(OUTPUT_C)
    MessageChannel outboundCollections();

@Output(OUTPUT_P)
MessageChannel outboundParse();

@Output(OUTPUT_CMP)
MessageChannel outboundCompare();

@Output(OUTPUT_R)
MessageChannel outboundReport();

@Output(OUTPUT_N)
MessageChannel outboundNotification();
```

The producer code is

```
public void sendCollectionTask(final MessageT message) {

        logger.info("Sending Collection Task :: " + message.toString());
        MessageChannel messageChannel = collectionStream.outboundCollections();
        boolean l_bool = messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message)
                .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
        logger.info("After sending message for Collection Task send status :: " + message.getTask().getId() + " : "
                + l_bool);
    }
```

When we start the application the producer produce the message properly but after some time we are receiving the error

```
2019-09-12 02:07:45,215 ERROR com.ericsson.tmo.cm.ccm.jobmanager.util.JobOrchestrator [scheduling-1] Error Trace ::
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@11328ab9]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform operation after producer has been closed
        at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:189)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:179)
```

The problem is resolve if we restart the application.
Thanks for your help.

Our Spring Cloud Config is

```
cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: kafka
          autoCreateTopic: false
          configuration:
            auto.offset.reset: latest
            max.request.size: 16777216
            buffer.memory: 67108864
      bindings:
        collection-out:
          destination: collection
          contentType: application/json
          group: collection
          producer:
            partitionCount: 5
            autoAddPartitions: true
```

Answer (score 4):

The exception message is clear.

> Cannot perform operation after producer has been closed

It can happen that your producer might be closed by one thread while on the other thread the producer is calling `send()` or the producer network thread is still sending the messages.

---

Since you are using Spring, I suppose that the `KafkaProducer` object is created for you and injected through Dependency Injection.

All you need to do is to figure out whoever uses *the same* `KafkaProducer`object and where the `close()` is called.

**Possible reasons**

1. Sometimes, it may happen that *same* `KafkaProducer` might be used by several other components of your same application (if you did not demarcate between several producers) and one of it might have closed it.

   *More clearly*, may be you are using the same producer bean instance for producing messages for different components in the same instance and somewhere it is closed.

   Typically, we have different producers producing to different topics since we have different producer configurations and topics for different types of data.
2. I have encountered a similar exception when I added a shutdown hook in which I was calling `producer.close()` while the other thread is trying to produce.

Comment: Can producer be closed by another Spring application instance or it's possible only from the same application?