# Nifi: PublishKafkaRecord: IllegalStateException: Cannot perform operation after producer has been closed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm using Apache Nifi to publish messages from CSV to a Kafka topic. 
See the flow in Nifi:
[image: Nifi Flow]
Therefore I use a `PublishKafkaRecord_2_0` Processor. See the following producer config:

[image: Producer Config Part 1]
[image: Producer Config Part 2]

It's the only Producer Running in Apache Nifi. But I get the error message:

```
IllegalStateException: Cannot perform operation after producer has been closed
```

There is no other producer which might close.
The only related topics, I found is the [same problem in spark](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Cannot-perform-operation-after-producer-has-been-closed-td38825.html) (where it was solved by setting a higher timeout. But I couldn't find this option in Nifi) and these [general tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57906995/spring-cloud-producer-exception-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-perfor), which didn't help me.

Any advice to solve this issue?  Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Include a screenshot of your flow & the PublishKafkaRecord config

Comment: What is the purpose of the SplitText and UpdateAttribute? These will add a significant bottle neck to your flow, and make using the PublishKafkaRecord processor a bit pointless, and might be causing your issue. You should commit to using Record processors for the flow and avoid splitting flowfiles where it isnt needed - this will also improve performance significantly. I don't see anything in your PublishKafka config that is even using the Attributes.

Comment: My problem was that the Kafka Cluster was secured via SSL, which I didn't know.